# How can I change my bluetooth speaker default passkey in Ubuntu

Tags: bluetooth

I have a bluetooth speaker that I can connect it to my Ubuntu with automatic passkey. It must have '0000' as it's default passkey but it's default passkey is '1111' and because of that, I'm not able to connect to this speaker using my android device.

Is there any way to change the device default passkey using Ubuntu? How can I change a connected bluetooth device configs using Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: Probably this one: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man5/hcid.conf.5.html (it should hold sections per device)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I don't think you can change the PIN of a bluetooth device. It is certainly hard-coded and you can't do anything about it.

Secondly, the right question to ask for your problem is: **How do I specify a different PIN than 0000 when pairing a bluetooth device on android** ?

So you better ask */your favortie search engine/* about that:

Comment: Thank you so much. I just realized that the PIN could not change from the outside with any software solution. Now I will continue to search around this problem by this question: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/115797/how-do-i-specify-a-different-pin-than-0000-when-pairing-a-bluetooth-device-on-an/115802?noredirect=1#comment143871_115802

Answer (score 0):

On pairing a new device from *Bluetooth settings...* we can specify any PIN a device needs.

After klicking on <kbd>+</kbd> in the bottom left corner we can give in *Pin options...* for automatic PIN selection (default) or for using a different fixed PIN for the device chosen. The PINs `0000`, `1111`, and `1234` can be selected from a radio button choice:

[image]

Comment: I want to change default PIN of my speaker. I know how to choose PIN option in my computer.

Comment: I suspected you do but I felt we need to complete this Q&A for other people who may come here. Changing the PIN of your device would not not be related to Ubuntu but is rather hardware specific. Many of such devices do have hard-coded PIN settings. Consult the manual of your device whether its PIN can be changes at all.